# Adding properties to response objects of existing API calls - bad idea?

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services

I have an API that exposes a few objects to the outside world via SOAP, XML, and JSON.

From an architectural standpoint, I'd like to add a few properties to the base class that these objects inherit from.

Logically, it would make sense to expose these properties to the outside world after the existing properties.

I'm just concerned that adding additional information may harm some of the clients, depending on how they coded things on their end. Note that none of our internal tests have shown any ill results from adding properties - the consuming clients just ignore the additional data.

Communicating this change to all clients may be difficult (which i admit is a separate issue).

Is this a legitimate concern?

Answer (score 1):

I feel this is a legitimate concern, you do not know how the service is being consumed.

A safe strategy is coding a new 'version' of your method. Leave the existing 'MyWebMethod' as it is and add 'MyWebMethodV2'. Send out communication of the new version's existance.

Comment: While I'd love to use that method, it brings in some complications. That really means that I'd be sending out different data-contracts based on what endpoint people call. Since the properties will be changed in the base class of the data object, not interface itself, the what would be the best way to handle that? Creating a new inheritance chain for every object doesn't sound doesn't sound practical.